# htaccess slash extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to force remove the file extension.

Example: domain.com/sub/index.html
 to should be automatically redirected to domain.com/sub/index  [With out trailing slash]

The .htaccess code I use is not what I really want. It allows index.html to exist and if typed domain.com/sub/index   it automatically redirects to domain.com/index/  [It goes to the root and adds a trailing slash]

Please help. Here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\im\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your base path, before any conditions are set, like so:

```
RewriteBase /sub
```

You also need to remove both slashes from your rule. So, `/$1/` would become `$1`